# Remove filter from MongoDB Profiling Level

Tags: mongodb

I ran the following query to enable MongoDB profiling but it does not seem to work as it is recording queries even with 0 millis.

```
db.setProfilingLevel( 2, { filter: { op: "query", millis: { $gt: 2000 } } } )
```

Now I am trying to remove the filter but there is no way I could find to unset it. I even tried the following but did not work.

```
db.setProfilingLevel( 0, 100 )
db.setProfilingLevel( 0, {} )
db.setProfilingLevel( 0, { $unset: {filter: "" } } )
```

```
{ 
    "was" : 0.0, 
    "slowms" : 100.0, 
    "sampleRate" : 1.0, 
    "filter" : {
        "$and" : [
            {
                "op" : {
                    "$eq" : "query"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "millis" : {
                    "$gt" : 2000.0
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "note" : "When a filter expression is set, slowms and sampleRate are not used for profiling and slow-query log lines."
}
```

Comment: The default is `db.setProfilingLevel( 0, 100)` try with that?

Comment: @Joe I did but the filter is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the string "unset" as the filter to remove it.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0,{filter:"unset"})
```

Comment: You are a genius!